# Java Time Complexity of Concatenating Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, time-complexity

What would be the time complexity associated with concatenating arrays? Not merging them as in merge sort, but simply concatenating them using `System.arraycopy()`. Thanks.

Comment: What do you think it would be? Why do you think so? Why do you have doubts?

Comment: Surely, it's just adding to the new array with all the entries of the other? Which would be O(n).

Comment: ^That's what I think, but I'm trying to ask for expertise from someone who might know more about the inner workings of the function.

Comment: read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18638743/is-it-better-to-use-system-arraycopy-than-a-fast-for-loop-for-copying-array

Comment: @Andreas - Rather than putting this on hold as a duplicate, I think this subject would benefit from a more canonical answer, referencing arraycopy()'s source code. Which could be difficult because it's probably written in C buried away somewhere.

Comment: @Rudi: I think it'd be more appropriate to add a more canonical answer to the question where this was asked originally, and mark duplicate questions as duplicates. Besides, `System.arraycopy()` can perform a native `memcpy` operation, for which we don't have source code, but whose complexity should be obvious.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - On second thoughts agreed. And besides that, after a little digging around the implementation of arraycopy() is platform dependent so there probably isn't a single canonical answer anyway.