# Fastest way to sort an array without overwriting it

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I want to sort an `int[] array` in Java, but store the sorted array as a new array instead of overwriting it.

The most obvious way to do this seems to be to create a copy of the array and then sort that new array, like so:

```
int[] a2 = new int[a.length];

for (int i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    a2[i] = a[i];
}

Arrays.sort(a2);
```

However, is there a faster way? Can we sort 'at the same time' as we copy the elements of the old array into the new one?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use

```
int[] a2 = IntStream.of(a).sorted().toArray();
```

But I doubt it's faster than

```
int[] a2 = a.clone();
Arrays.sort(a2);
```

Regardless it's the same complexity, so don't expect more than a constant factor speedup.

Answer (score 2):

To sort a new array while iterating the old won't be faster. For this you can use [System.arraycopy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) instead of create your own sorting or copy function.

> Copies an array from the specified source array, beginning at the specified position, to the specified position of the destination array.

Example:

```
int[] a1 = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};  // I suppose a1...
int[] a2 = new int[a1.length];

System.arraycopy( a1, 0, a2, 0, a1.length );

Arrays.sort(a2);
```

---

**UPDATE:** As long as you are asking for *the faster* way of sort an array, as you have seen there is a long discussion about if copying it or sorting on the fly will be best option. For that you can try to make some benchmark. But if you use copy to sort it **you will find here that [all depends of the size and elements of the array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18639042/3850595).**.

Comment: Yes, but the question was how to avoid copying first. And if you are going to copy, there is the more concise `int[] a2 = Arrays.copyOf(a1, a1.length)`;

Comment: not actually... OP asks: *is there a faster way?* to sort while iterating is OP and your guess to achieve faster way...

Comment: @JordiCastilla: *"Can we sort **'at the same time'** as we copy the elements of the old array into the new one?"*

Comment: but to be faster! OP ask for a faster way and guess if sort while iterating could be faster...

Answer (score 0):

If you are inclined towards using `TreeSet`, the following code may serve the purpose:

```
TreeSet<Integer> copied = new TreeSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    copied.add(i);
}
```

I tried to test the difference and it actually depends on the size of the data as well as data in the array.

However, I cannot comment on how deterministic is this method, but I sure will run a few experiments and post my findings here.

**UPDATE:**

I used the following code to test the performance of `TreeSet`

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.TreeSet;

class TestArrayCopy {

    public static void main(String[] arg) throws java.io.IOException {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            int arr[] = randomArray();
            System.out.println("Array Size: " + arr.length + ". Results for case #" + i);
            System.out.println("Using Array Copy:");
            copyAndSort(arr);
            System.out.println("Using Tree Set:");
            useTreeSet(arr);
            System.out.println("----------------------------");
        }
    }

    public static void copyAndSort(int array[]) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            int copied[] = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
            Arrays.sort(copied);
        }
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(end - start);
    }

    public static void useTreeSet(int array[]) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            TreeSet<Integer> copied = new TreeSet<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                copied.add(i);
            }
        }
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(end - start);
    }

    public static int[] randomArray() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int len = 100000 + random.nextInt(1000000);
        int arr[] = new int[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            arr[i] = random.nextInt(1000000);
        }
        return arr;
    }

}
```

The following results were achieved on Core-i7 64-bit System with Java 8:

> Array Size: 616568. Results for case #1 
>  Using Array Copy: 
>   7692926921
>  Using Tree Set:
>  16336650396
>   ----------------------------
>  Array Size: 390270. Results for case #2
>  Using Array Copy:
>  4441066232
>  Using Tree Set:
>  9306742954
>   ----------------------------
>  Array Size: 658410. Results for case #3
>  Using Array Copy:
>  8534144532
>  Using Tree Set:
>  17721764026
>   ----------------------------
>  Array Size: 1021396. Results for case #4
>  Using Array Copy:
>  13573512678
>  Using Tree Set:
>  31341152398
>   ----------------------------
>  Array Size: 1034872. Results for case #5
>  Using Array Copy:
>  13298690836
>  Using Tree Set:
>  30950793986
>   ----------------------------
>  Array Size: 466014. Results for case #6
>  Using Array Copy:
>  5501196272
>  Using Tree Set:
>  11704757934
>   ----------------------------
>  Array Size: 190231. Results for case #7
>  Using Array Copy:
>  1662270714
>  Using Tree Set:
>  4465174267
>   ----------------------------
>  Array Size: 681150. Results for case #8
>  Using Array Copy:
>  8262756493
>  Using Tree Set:
>  19079310588
>   ----------------------------
>  Array Size: 627257. Results for case #9
>  Using Array Copy:
>  6725984653
>  Using Tree Set:
>  14468898852
>   ----------------------------
>  Array Size: 397189. Results for case #10
>  Using Array Copy:
>  3122214311
>  Using Tree Set:
>  7356182877
>   ----------------------------

From these results, it can be seen that TreeSet is a lot slower than sorting a duplicate array. Good exercise for me.

Comment: There are many problems with this benchmark. You need to do a proper warmup (run both algorithms in a tight loop say, 10.000-100.000 times each before measuring runtime) and you should use nanoTime instead of currentTimeMillis.

Comment: Also, you need to do `copied.toArray(...)` to get back the actual result.

Comment: I am updating my code for benchmarking, this was just a quick check. About copied.toArray() on TreeSet, I would like to measure performance without that just for the sake of testing.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are many problems with benchmarking the way you did. There are so many factors that have nothing to do with the actual code which are included in this measurement. For example warmup times and CPU cache priming from the previous runs. The only way to make a measurements which is not off by half a second is to use a benchmrk framework.

Answer (score 0):

int[] a2 = IntStream.of(a).sorted().toArray();