# How to convert ArrayList of Strings to char array

Tags: java, arraylist

The following code converts `ArrayList<String>` to `char[]` and print output which appears as `[back, pack]`. Here, the `char[]` includes `','` and `' '`. Is there a way to do it in another way to get rid of comma and space?

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("back");
list.add("pack");

char[] chars = list.toString().toCharArray();

for (char i : chars){
   System.out.print(i);
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea in general to rely on the behaviour of toString. Whilst something like ArrayList is unlikely to change the implementation of toString, other classes might, which would mean any code you write relying it it will no longer work as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace the this line

```
char[] chars = list.toString().toCharArray();
```

with below two lines

```
String str=list.toString().replaceAll(",", "");
char[] chars = str.substring(1, str.length()-1).replaceAll(" ", "").toCharArray();
```

Comment: Hey just one question if I may, that why can't we replace both the space and comma as if they were one

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by joining the `String`s in your `ArrayList<String>` and then getting `char[]` from the result:

```
char[] chars = list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining()).toCharArray();
```

Here `.stream.collect(Collectors.joining())` part is Java 8 Stream way to join a sequence of `Strings` into one. See: [`Collectors.joining()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining--) docs.

If you want any delimiter between the parts in the result, use `Collectors.joining(delimiter)` instead.

There's also an overload which adds prefix and suffix to the result, for example, if you want `[` and `]` in it, use `Collectors.joining("", "[", "]")`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `toString` method on `list` is what is adding the comma and space, it's a `String` representation of your `list`. As `list` is a collection of `String`s you don't need to call `toString` on it, just iterate through the collection converting each `String` into an array of chars using `toCharArray` (I assume you will probably want to add all the chars of all the Strings together).

Comment: The answer doesn't provide a way to convert `ArrayList<String>` to `char[]`.

Comment: That is true, it was sort of implied by "manipulate the data how you want it". I was trying to point out the error he was getting. I'll amend the answer though.

Answer (score 2):

String to charArray in Java Code:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
list.add( "back" );
list.add( "pack" );
for ( String string : list )
{
    for ( char c : string.toCharArray() )
    {
        chars.add( c );
    }
}
System.out.println( chars );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an example how should you resolved large list to array copy. Beware number of characters must be less then Integer.MAX. This code is just an example how it could be done. There are plenty of checks that one must implement it to make that code works properly.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class WrappedList {

    //Or replace with some better counter
    int totalCharCount = 0;
    final List<String> list;

    public WrappedList() {
        this(new ArrayList<String>());
    }

    public WrappedList(final List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void add(final String toAdd) {
        if(toAdd != null) {
            totalCharCount += toAdd.length();
            this.list.add(toAdd);
        }
    }

    public List<String> getList() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
    }

    public char[] toCharArray() {
        return this.toCharArray(this.totalCharCount);
    }


    public char[] toCharArray(final int charCountToCopy) {
        final char[] product = new char[charCountToCopy];
        int buffered = 0;
        for (String string : list) {
            char[] charArray = string.toCharArray();
            System.arraycopy(charArray, 0, product, buffered, charArray.length);
            buffered += charArray.length;
        }
        return product;
    }

    //Utility method could be used  also as stand-alone class
    public char[] toCharArray(final List<String> all) {
        int size = all.size();
        char[][] cpy = new char[size][];
        for (int i = 0; i < all.size(); i++) {
            cpy[i] = all.get(i).toCharArray();
        }
        int total = 0;
        for (char[] cs : cpy) {
            total += cs.length;
        }
        return this.toCharArray(total);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Add String iteratively
        WrappedList wrappedList = new WrappedList();
        wrappedList.add("back");
        wrappedList.add("pack");
        wrappedList.add("back1");
        wrappedList.add("pack1");
        final char[] charArray = wrappedList.toCharArray();
        System.out.println("Your char array:");
        for (char c : charArray) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }

        //Utility method one time for all, should by used in stand-alone Utility class
        System.out.println("As util method");
        System.out.println(wrappedList.toCharArray(wrappedList.getList()));
    }

}
```

See also: [system-arraycopy-than-a-for-loop-for-copying-arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18638743/is-it-better-to-use-system-arraycopy-than-a-for-loop-for-copying-arrays)